# Stopping program with button Tkinter Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pthreads

I have a program that works with an user interface : I start it using a button and I would like to have the possibility to stop it during the process using the user interface:

[image]

The problem is : When I start the program, I cannot click on any buttons because when I drag the mouse in the tkinter window I have the "looping" / "waiting" cursor and it doesn't allow me to click on any buttons inside the interface.

I tried to start the infinit loop function in a new thread, but I don't know if it is really a good way to solve my problem... Any of you have any solutions ?

I try to simulate my problem with a simple code :

```
from tkinter import *
import loop


window = Tk()
window.title("test")

start = Button(window, text="start", bg ="green", command=loop.start)
stop  = Button(window, text="stop", bg ="green", command=loop.stop)
thread = Button(window, text="threads", bg ="green", command=loop.how_many_threads)

start.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
stop.grid(column = 2, row = 1)
thread.grid(column = 3 , row = 1)



window.mainloop()
```

and few functions :

```
import threading

continu = True



def infinit(x):
    cpt = 0
    while(x):
        cpt += 1
        #print(cpt)

    print("loop is over !")

def start():
    threadSimulation = threading.Thread(target= infinit(continu)).start()

def stop():
    self.continu = False

def how_many_threads():
    for t in threading.enumerate():
        print("thread names : ",t.getName())
```

Comment: Your implementation is wrong, but the concept is ok. For blocking IO bound applications threading is a great way to run them and keep the tkinter window active. If it's a good solution *for you* depends on what you are actually trying to do; is your actual problem a blocking IO bound application?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to fix your implementation. The biggest error is that you have to provide arguments to the thread in the `args` part, not like a normal function call.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

def infinit(x):
    cpt = 0
    while(continu):
        cpt += 1
        print(cpt)
        time.sleep(1)
    print("loop is over !")

def start():
    threadSimulation = threading.Thread(target= infinit, args=(continu,))
    threadSimulation.daemon = True
    threadSimulation.start()

def stop():
    global continu
    continu = False

def how_many_threads():
    for t in threading.enumerate():
        print("thread names : ",t.getName())

continu = True

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("test")

start = tk.Button(window, text="start", bg ="green", command=start)
stop  = tk.Button(window, text="stop", bg ="green", command=stop)
thread = tk.Button(window, text="threads", bg ="green", command=how_many_threads)

start.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
stop.grid(column = 2, row = 1)
thread.grid(column = 3 , row = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You used `continu` directly inside `infinit()`, so the argument `x` is not necessary.  Or `continu` should be `x` instead inside `infinit()`?

Comment: If you pass the variable in it won't work, unless it's mutable. So that's why I used the global. But I left the argument even though it's not needed just to show how arguments are passed into threads, since that's what was causing OP's original problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to close the program, you can use "window.quit" in the command section of your button like this:

```py
stop = Button(window, text="stop", bg ="green", command=window.quit)
```